# How to align TextView with background in Layout - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, textview

I've got a small problem.

I've got:

[image]

I want: (but the text few dp from the left)

[image]

Is it possible? Here is a whole code of my layout: **(@+id/txtname is the textview from the screenshot!)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/md_brown_100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
                android:textColor="@color/md_amber_700"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text=""/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_width="150dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_above="@+id/txtname"
                  android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_width="48dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtname"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_dollar_ss"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/AliceBlue"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:layout_width="153dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtdesc"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:maxLines="3"

                android:textColor="#80869c"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsizeearncredit_desc"
                android:text="This is a description of the offer and this is just a demo to show off 3 lines stacking correctly on top of each other"
                android:layout_weight="0.55"
                android:layout_width="140dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextArrow"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:tint="@color/md_grey_300"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="@dimen/two" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me guys! Thanks a lot of You can give me any idea of it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your LinearLayout has a padding of 5dp, which keeps your "Invite Friends" TextView away from the edge.

Replace

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="150dp">
```

with

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="150dp">
```

This way you will have no padding on the left. To compensate it on the description text, add `android:paddingStart="5dp"` to your TextView `txtdesc`

Comment: Great solution! Thank you, but how to make the background stay at the place i want, and the text few dp from the left border?

Comment: check the comment above

Comment: you can add `android:paddingStart` to your LinearLayout and set how many dp you want it away from left border. Note that if you set it to 5dp, you will get the original result. What's happening to the background?

Comment: Works! Thank You a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

Although im fairly new to Android Studio, i'd recommend you to try changing the layout gravity property on that specific TextView to adjust itself to the left corner and/or try forcing a padding to the left aswell.

Though this is just a guess of what could solve it, i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

set layout gravity of that view to `android:layout_gravity="left"`

Answer (score 0):

solution:---
Please add following property within name textview .
`android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtname"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtname"
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtdesc"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="This is a description of the offer and this is just a demo to show off 3 lines stacking correctly on top of each other"
            android:textColor="#80869c" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nextArrow"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding attribute for the linear layout encompassing the text and image view should be set to 0.

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

This includes paddings left & right, hence the purple colour has a slight gap, remove the padding and the purple shape will reach the sides of the container shape.

I noticed you only want the purple shape to touch the RHS, hence we only want to remove the paddingLeft.

```
  android:paddingRight="5dp"
  android:paddingLeft="0dp"
  android:paddingBottom="5dp"
  android:paddingTop="5dp"
```

The TextView's gravity attribute must then be set to 'left'

```
  android:gravity="left"
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you, but how to make the background stay at the place i want, and the text few dp from the left border?

Comment: @DawidWalczyk add paddingLeft to the TextView, please up vote my answer if it helped.

Your welcome.